# Reset without losing already committed files

Tags: git, git-reset

When I accidentally committed a file to the wrong branch, I normally use `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. However, using this method I generally lose all the files committed. Is there a way to reset a commit, without losing the edited files?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

do not use `--hard` use `--soft` instead.

Thus if you want to remove your latest commit you'd do:

`git reset --soft HEAD^`

Comment: @cherrun, also consider reading [Reset Demystified](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html).

Comment: +1 for a short and accurate answer. To sum up, use: 
`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Comment: [reset demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) has moved

Answer (score 5):

While Alex is very correct, I might be tempted to try a different sequence:

If I wanted the commit on a yet-to-be-born branch:

```
git branch newbranch
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If I wanted the commit on an existing branch:

```
git checkout otherbranch
git cherry-pick firstbranch
git checkout firstbranch
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

The full example of Alex's answer

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git checkout otherbranch
git commit -am "Message"
```

Note the last example will fail poorly if the attempt to "float" the change to the other branch fails due to conflicts.  You will then need to stash/checkout/apply to get into conflict resolution.

Comment: great answer! I think this is about only throwing some changes away that were made in the last commit and keeping the other half. In that case you would just throw away the commit and adding the changes again, that you intend to keep. in this case `git add --interactive` might be useful too!

Answer (score 2):

for my case, i prefer using `--mixed` instead, after i found [this simple explanation](https://davidzych.com/difference-between-git-reset-soft-mixed-and-hard/)

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```